# ANSI colors don't work in VSCode integrated terminal with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for my python project and I am also using [flakeheaven](https://flakeheaven.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (fork of the unmaintained [flakehell](https://github.com/life4/flakehell) package) to manage `flake8` and other linters/plugins. When running `flakeheaven lint`, it tries to print the output nicely with colors. Here's how it looks on my terminal (Windows terminal using Powershell Core):

[image]

I like this feature. However, When I run the `lint` command in the integrated terminal in VSCode, it doesn't display the colors, and instead displays weird ANSI sequences:

[image]

It looks like VSCode can't display the ANSI colors correctly in the terminal. I'd like to know if there is a way to fix this to get the same colorful output as in the external terminal.

Is there a way to make VSCode terminal display colored ANSI output correctly?

Comment: Related: [Weird PowerShell prompt](/q/75428157)

Comment: The text contains esc sequences that looks like they are from a terminal like an old VT100 escape sequences.  See : https://larsfosdal.blog/2018/08/31/did-you-know-that-you-can-enable-vt100-terminal-emulation-in-powershell-as-well-as-the-cmd-window/?force_isolation=true