# How to fix ANSI colors encoding in VSCode Git Log?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, logging, colors, ansi-escape

I'm trying to run a pre-commit hook that runs lint-staged. When I commit my staged files using Windows PowerShell, I get the following result:
[image: Result of lint-staged on Windows powershell]

But when I try to commit the files VScode Source Control, it outputs the result to Git Log, which looks like this:
[image: Result of lint-staged on Git Log]

Do you know how can I fix this bad encoding? I suspect that it happens because it probably missing ANSI colors support.
I found some related topics:

1. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38834#issuecomment-454798872 (I tried the suggested extension, but it didn't work for me).
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cannot-get-ansi-colors-to-work-in-vs-code-git-bash-integrated-terminal
3. [ANSI colors don't work in VSCode integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362968/ansi-colors-dont-work-in-vscode-integrated-terminal)

Thanks

Comment: Those ESC [ <number>  m sequences *are* the color coding, as you suspect. How to make any particular bit of software display them *as* color-encoding is a question about that one specific bit of software (so here, about vscode). With the `less` pager that many use with base Git, for instance, the `-r` and `-R` options (pick one of the two) tell `less` to let those through to a terminal emulator. I don't know if vscode uses `less` and if so, whether it disables the `-R` option that Git normally sets.